# VS Express 2012 - VB.Net code stopping without breakpoints

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm trying to code a DFS maze generation algorithm. Everything was going alright up to a point, and now the debugger isn't working properly: I've removed all breakpoints, but when I run the code, the code stops at a certain line that isn't a readkey or readline or loop. There's no breakpoint there, there's no reason that it should stop. When I press continue, it stops again; when I press pause it's stopped at another random line, and I keep repeating this process but it keeps happening.

```
If Not (CurrentCell.Info And 128) = 128 Then
Int = Random.Next(1, 5)
If (Maze(TempCell.Pos.Y, TempCell.Pos.X).Info And 15) = 15 Then
Int = Random.Next(1, 5)
If Not (CurrentCell.Info And 64) = 64 Then
TempCell.Pos = New Location(CurrentCell.Pos.X, CurrentCell.Pos.Y - 1)
TempCell.Info = Maze(TempCell.Pos.Y, TempCell.Pos.X).Info
```

The code apparently stops for the first time at random times, according to the count of a stack I've used.

I've used random numbers several times throughout the code, but I can't see any reason why the resulting code would cause the debugger to stop without a breakpoint.

I've tried copying the whole code into a new project, but the same problem occurs.

I haven't included the code because it's long, but if it would be better if I included it, let me know.

I couldn't find help on this issue, most people seem to be having the opposite problem of the debugger failing to hit a breakpoint. Can anyone suggest any solutions?

Comment: Q: Is there any chance (the code you're *not* showing us!) might be going into an infinite loop, or an infinite recursion?  Q: Don't you need an "end if" when you break your statements into two lines (I haven't used VB in a *long* time...)?

Comment: The code is quite long. I could show it all to you if it would be helpful, but that's the only reason I didn't post it. Would you like me to?

Comment: I should clarify that the lines I showed you were disconnected lines, each examples of where the debugger stopped, and that that wasn't one block of code!

Comment: I worked out the issue, it was very simple, and just as you suggested - it was an infinite loop. I'd messed up a boolean condition!